# for IOS, Google Maps SDK works on simulator but crashes on device

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

The map view is to display one place. And it is working fine on simulator.

Here is the crash log on device, thanks a lot for the help.

```
#0  0x0000000194c85d74 in std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#1  0x00000001001bd55c in std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> >::pair(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> const&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/utility:229
#2  0x00000001001bd548 in std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> >::pair(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> const&) [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/utility:229
#3  0x00000001001bd548 in bool google::protobuf::InsertIfNotPresent<std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::pair<void const*, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> > > >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> >(std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::pair<void const*, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> > > >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::pair<void const*, int> const&) at /Users/lli/work/zoute_ios/ThirdParty/Protobuf/google/protobuf/stubs/map-util.h:136
#4  0x00000001001b8ad0 in google::protobuf::SimpleDescriptorDatabase::DescriptorIndex<std::__1::pair<void const*, int> >::AddFile(google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto const&, std::__1::pair<void const*, int>) at /Users/lli/work/zoute_ios/ThirdParty/Protobuf/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:56
#5  0x00000001956632a8 in google::protobuf::EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add(void const*, int) ()
#6  0x00000001956415f4 in google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int) ()
#7  0x0000000195669e00 in google::protobuf::protobuf_AddDesc_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto() ()
#8  0x000000019567f28c in _GLOBAL__I_a ()
#9  0x0000000120053e3c in ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) ()
....
#33 0x00000001003fff1c in -[GMSAsyncInitServices sharedInitWithSync:] ()
#34 0x00000001003ffda4 in -[GMSAsyncInitServices initSync] ()
#35 0x000000010040086c in +[GMSServices sharedServicesSync] ()
#36 0x00000001003f74e4 in -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:] ()
#37 0x00000001003f6cf4 in -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] ()
#38 0x00000001003f6b58 in +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] ()
```

Comment: Did you try adding Exception Breakpoint?

Comment: yes, the same crash. it crashes at "InsertIfNotPresent(&by_name_, file.name(), value)", where file.name() returns null.

Comment: The crash is caused by symbol collisions. Find the solution  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848118/weird-ios-libprotobuf-dylib-cause-crash